# White screen when attaching css to function.php

Tags: theme-development, css, javascript

When i attach below line code i get white screen and in console log it is getting below error my browsers are up to date

Code

```
body:not(.no-transition) #wrapper, .animsition-overlay {    position: relative;     opacity: 0;     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both; }
```

Console log error

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
>   jquery-migrate.min.js:2:552 Animsition: Element does not exist on
>   page. plugins.js:428:1211 Animsition: Does not support this browser.
>   plugins.js:428:1273

Answer (score 1):

"White screen" generally means there is a PHP error preventing the page from being generated. You should [check your WordPress error log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) (wp-content/debug.log by default) for any relevant errors.

Adding CSS code would not prevent the page from loading.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a default **(if that exists)** WordPress *css* attribute name may have a conflict with the attribute names in your *css* .

Try changing your *css* names to something different of **more descriptive**,

An example name that I've seen bring conflict/WSOD **aka:** "White Screen Of Death" in WordPress is `.page`

Try avoiding words like:

1. blog
2. wordpress
3. wp
4. header
5. footer

... or anything generic in your *css*

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would bad CSS cause a white screen of death? That's usually server side. I suppose if you have a completely client-side-rendered site then maybe, but that's unusual for WordPress and duplicate CSS isn't likely to do that.